# Can you write out log messages to the TortoiseSVN Commit Finished dialog?

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn, post-commit-hook

Can you write out log messages to the TortoiseSVN Commit Finished dialog?
I know that you can output to the TortoiseSVN dialog in C# using 
`Console.Error.WriteLine("error message");
 Environment.Exit(1);`
but I cannot find the the way to just output information. Is there a way to just add notes to this dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I clearly didn't understand your question. If you want to access the log file externally without using the GUI, you can use command line( it needs to be enabled on installation). Its so simple like

```
svn log PATH
```

You can also save the log as XML using this code

```
svn log -v --xml > repository_log.xml
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I don't want to access a log file. When you  try to commit something in tortoiseSVN and it fails because of something in your pre commit hook (for example you don't allow people to commit with blank comments) there is an error message that shows up on the tortoiseSVN commit failed dialog. You are able to pass in what that error message says in the pre commit hook. I was looking for a way to output a message if it didn't error.